# Self-biased JFET - Midpoint bias: Why set the drain voltage to one-half of it?

Tags: transistors, jfet, fet

To set a midpoint bias, I understand that ID = IDSS/2 (and by equation, VGS = VGS(off)/3.4).

For calculating resistor values, why set VD = VDD/2?

[image]

Comment: More info is required, include a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: One-half of **what**? Include a circuit or no answers for you.

Comment: I have add one!